Eclipse- Maven-Hibernate Error configuration
enter image description here
I'm trying to configure eclise with hibernate, but I get the following error when I try to create the cfg file.
How do I solve it?
Thank you.
I use eclipse 2024-6, MySQL Connector/J 8.3.0, Jboss 4.29.1 Final, jdk22
I tried deleting the .m2 folder, but don't work.
I started eclipse with clean command, but it doesn't work.
eclipse.buildId=4.32.0.20240606-1231
java.version=22.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -clean

org.eclipse.ui
Error
Mon Aug 05 14:49:29 CEST 2024
Unhandled event loop exception

java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaNature cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject (org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaNature and org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject are in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @529500a7)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.wizards.NewConfigurationWizard.init(NewConfigurationWizard.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode.getWizard(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WizardSelectionPage.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:915)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3673)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:271)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1481)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1454)


Please go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue. Can the issue also be reproduced with JBoss Tools 4.30.x.Nightly?

Please edit your question and follow exactly the instructions from my first comment. Currently, the question shows only the first part of the logged error, without the stack trace which would be important to know.

It's a bug; the idiom of casting the nature in this way no longer works. Same problem reported for a different area of code at https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBIDE-29207 .

As @nitind already said, it's a bug of the JBoss Tools caused by this cast here (see log: at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.wizards.NewConfigurationWizard.init(NewConfigurationWizard.java:325)). The fix might be to change the mentioned line to jproj =  JavaCore.create((IProject)selection.getFirstElement());.

I created a pull request: https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-hibernate/pull/2549

Thank you.
How can I use your solution? Where does Eclipse save the java files to edit?

This must be compiled and built. If the pull request is accepted, the change will probably be in the next nightly build. Best you comment on the pull request and tell that you will test the change.
